# What is the physics dynamics behind inset patch antenna radiation

Tags: antenna

I know that the radiation from an antenna is caused by a fringing field between the patch and the ground.
I also know that the length of the antenna is lamba/2, so both fringing field radiation will add together.
But this is only intuition.
Is there some actual explanation regarding the physical dynamics of an inset fed patch antenna?

Comment: Hi! Yes. It starts out with the basics of field theory, i.e. Maxwell's equations (I guess you know them?) and requires a bit of transmission line theory (otherwise the inset as impedance matcher is really hard to understand) and finally requires aperture antenna theory. It's like, 2 full years of studying at university. So, I think your question is a bit broad! However, start with the first thing you're unfamiliar with: if that's Maxwell's equations, these. If transmission line theory is, but Maxwell sits well with you, that's where you start.

Comment: There are standing waves set the impedance and the radiation pattern.

Is there some manual i could follow about the inset feed,how it effects the standing waves and how it impoves impedance?
same thing about the radiation pattern ,why at half wavelength length we get optimal directivity?(standing wave)